# Handlle image orientation in GridView android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using the code below to display the device images in a GridView.
But I am getting an image orientation problem while displaying them in the GridView.

Some images are showing in horizontal orientation mode

[image: like this]

```
public class MultiImagePicActivity extends Activity {

GridView mGrid;

static public String[] arrPath,modifiedArrayPath;
private int ids[];
private int count;
static int selectCount;
Activity act=this;
Context ctx=this;
ArrayList<String> imagepaths;
public static int count1 = 0;
public static String classs;
static int maximageselection;
static int width,height;
//int sel=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //now get Intent Extras
    Bundle extras;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) 

    {

    //fetching extra data passed with intents in a Bundle type variable

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras == null)

    {        maximageselection= 0;
    classs=null;
    }

    else

    {            /* fetching the string passed with intent using ‘extras’*/

        maximageselection= extras.getInt("maximage");
        classs=extras.getString("From");

    }

    }


    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
    imagepaths=new ArrayList<String>();
    imagepaths.clear();
    loadApps();

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_1);
    mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);

    mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterxtends());

    mGrid.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    mGrid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());

}

    private void loadApps() {




    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i <this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    imagecursor.close();

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();

}
public class ImageAdapterxtends extends BaseAdapter{
    CheckableLayout l;
    ImageView i;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrPath[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(MultiImagePicActivity.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            l = new CheckableLayout(MultiImagePicActivity.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            l.addView(i);
        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }
        try {
            setBitmap(i, ids[position]);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return l;

    }


    }

    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv,final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            Bitmap myBitmap;
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //iv.setImageBitmap(result);
                setMyBitmap(result);
            }
            public final void setMyBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

                  if (this.myBitmap != null) {
                    this.myBitmap.recycle();
                  }
                  this.myBitmap = bitmap;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().height = width/3;
                  iv.getLayoutParams().width = width/3;
                  iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
        }.execute();
    }





public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {

        mChecked = checked;
        setForeground(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tr) : null);

    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}

public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
        GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        //return true;
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_ok:
                if(classs.equals("SliderExistingDetailedActivity")){
            Intent i = new Intent();
                modifiedArrayPath=imagepaths.toArray(new String[imagepaths.size()]);
                i.putExtra("selectedImagepath", modifiedArrayPath);
                //i.putExtra("data", selectedPath);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
                }else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MultiImagePicActivity.this, AudioSelectActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra("IMAGEPATHS", imagepaths);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", 1);
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        selectCount = mGrid.getCheckedItemCount();
        if(checked){
            imagepaths.add(arrPath[position]);
            if(selectCount>maximageselection){

                imagepaths.remove(arrPath[position]);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MultiImagePicActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Restriction")
                .setMessage("You can add at max "+maximageselection+" images !!!")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // continue with delete
                        mGrid.refreshDrawableState();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                 })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                 .show();

            }           
        }
        else{
            imagepaths.remove(arrPath[position]);
        }

        switch (selectCount) {
        case 1:
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            break;
        default:
            mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
            break;
        }
    }
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: Is your image rotated? I not found any code to rotate images in your code.

Comment: Sir in my device the default app which is provided by manufacturer showing all the images in correct orientation.but in my code some of the images shows in wrong orientation.

Comment: i have try like this http://jpst.it/yozZ also but its not working.

Comment: Add `MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION` to your colums[] and inspect the value in your for loop. Are they different for the rotated ones?